# MVC3 show appropriate partial view based on selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

So i have **View1** and in there I have:

```
<ul>
<li><a>First item</a></li>
<li><a>Second Item</a></li>
</ul>

//Some Partial View Placeholder
```

When a user click on **First Item**, I want the Partial View Placeholder to Load a **FirstView**, and when user clicks on **Second Item**, I want the Partial View to load a **SecondView**.

Each of **Partial View's need save information in View1's model info**.

How is best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either load both partials into two divs on the page and use javascript to hook into any clicks on first and second item, and to change visibility of the relevant div.

Or if you don't want both partials loaded on the page at the same time, you could make your placeholder an empty div and use something like jQuery.Ajax. When first or second item is clicked, make an asynchronous call to the relevant partial view and inject the returned html directly into the div placeholder.